# setting the protocol back to default values

Tags: git

I was cloning some git repository but git was not accessible - because of some network issues. so I tried changing the default protocol for git like this

git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/

Likewise I tried it for some other URLs too as they were also not working - but in hit and trial, I made some mistakes in URLs, and those stopped working. Now I want to set the protocol  back to default - for each URL. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your global settings should all be in your `.gitconfig` file in your user's home directory.  On a Linux or OS X machine, you'd try:

```
vim ~/.gitconfig
```

And you'll see your changes, and can delete them line by line.  If you're on a Windows machine, someone else will hopefully know where you should look. :)